# how to make function recognize id's of dynamically created elements in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {                           
        $('#somebutton').click(function() {                  
            $.get('List', function(responseJson) {   
                $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) {
                    var elem=$('<input type="checkbox" id="item" value='+item+'/> ' + item + '<br />');
                    $('#somediv').append('<input type="checkbox" id="item" value='+item+'/> ' + item + '<br />');
                });
                $('#somediv').append('<button id="newButton">'+"retrieve"+'</button> <br />');
            });
        });
        $("#newButton").click(function(){     
            var data = { 'checkBoxList[]' : []};     
            var list=$(":input:item:checked");    
            $(list.each(function() {        
                data['checkBoxList[]'].push($(this).val());     
                }));     
            $.get("Data",data,function(responseText){
                $('#somediv').text(responseText);
                }); 
            }); 
    });
```

(i'm new to jQuery)
What i'm trying to do is 
call a servlet ,which then gives me some list of checkboxes

select the required ones and then again submit to another servlet
which takes inputs from checkboxes 
to display the info based on selection.

getting list of checkboxes from servlet is working fine, which creates dynamically a button also
when i clicked the button, it doesn't do anything , i donno why

Comment: What's your question? Do you have a problem with your code?

Comment: Check out [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for jQuery 1.7+ or [`.delgate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for older versions. These will allow you to bind event handlers that automatically recognize new elements. So when the new button gets added, it's click handler will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing I could use a `class` because with your current implementation you could end up with multiple buttons with the same id.

So what you can do is:

```
    $(".newButton").live('click', function(){     
        var data = { 'checkBoxList[]' : []};     
        var list=$(":input:item:checked");    
        $(list.each(function() {        
            data['checkBoxList[]'].push($(this).val());     
            }));     //why is this like this *
        $.get("Data",data,function(responseText){
            $('#somediv').text(responseText);
        }); 
    });
```

---

Also I am not sure what you are doing here:

```
            $(list.each(function() {        
                data['checkBoxList[]'].push($(this).val());     
            }));     //why is this like this *
```

Just do:

```
            list.each(function() {        
                data['checkBoxList[]'].push($(this).val());     
            });
```

Comment: i'm trying to get the checked items which were created by previous function and then send tht list to servlet for furthur processing